# Adding product to DB via prepared statement from textfield parameters

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I'm doing a project for school -thought i would try to expand the application and i'm kind of stuck at this.

I'm trying to add a product to an Oracle Thin database from the textfields in the form with a prepared statement.

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {

            Class.forName(DB.driver);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB.URL, DB.ID, DB.PW);

            String query = "insert into parts values (?, '?', ?, ?, ?)";
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pno")));
            statement.setString(2, request.getParameter("pname"));
            statement.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("qoh")));
            statement.setDouble(4, Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price")));
            statement.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("olevel")));
            statement.executeQuery(query);



        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ee) {
            System.out.println("Connection failed!");
            System.err.println(ee);
        } finally {

            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(addProductServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(addProductServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("indexSuccess.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
```

The product is not being added to the database, however if I hardcode the SQL-query it works just fine. I have checked that all datatypes are correct.

The form looks as follows:

```
<form action="addProductServlet">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom-5" placeholder="Product No. (100XX)" name="pno" required>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom-5" placeholder="Product Name" name="pname" required>   
                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom-5" placeholder="Quantity (XX)" name="qoh" required>   
                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom-5" placeholder="Price (XX.XX)" name="price" required>   
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Order Level" name="olevel" required>      
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-danger nice-bg-color" type="submit">Add product</button>
</form>
```

Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `query` to

```
String query = "insert into parts values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Notice, that the `String` parameters do not require to be quoted as the `PrepareStatement` does that for you. Adding quotes would result in a bounded value of `,''value'',` and break the final query *statement*.